# NoMethodError in Workshops#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

newbie here...Learning ruby on rails about 4 weeks, first project, can´t find whats wrong, would appreciate some help.

_form (error in line 2):

```
<%= simple_form_for @workshop, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
 <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Escolher Categoria") %>

 <%= f.file_field :workshop_img %>
 <%= f.input :title, label: "Nome do Workshop" %>
 <%= f.input :description, label: "Descrição" %>
 <%= f.input :author, label: "Formador" %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
```

workshops_controller:

```
class WorkshopsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_workshop, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
if params[:category].blank?
    @workshops = Workshop.all.order("created_at DESC")  
else
  @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
  @workshops = Workshop.where(:category_id =>   @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
end  
end

def show    
end 

def new
@workshop = current_user.workshops.build
@categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
end


def create
  @workshop = current_user.workshops.build(workshop_params)
  @workshop.category_id = params[:category_id ]

  if @workshop.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end     
  end

def edit
  @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
end

def update
  @workshop.category_id = params[:category_id]
  if @workshop.update(workshop_params)
    redirect_to workshop_path(@workshop)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end       
end

def destroy
  @workshop.destroy
  redirect_to root_path 
end


private
  def workshop_params
    params.require(:workshop).permit(:title, :description, :author, :category_id, :workshop_img)
  end

def find_workshop 
  @workshop = Workshop.find(params[:id])    
end    
end
```

category model

```
has_many :workshops
end
```

user model

```
has_many :workshops
```

workshop model

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category

 has_attached_file :workshop_img, styles: { workshop_index: "250x350>",    workshop_show: "325x475>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"

validates_attachment_content_type :workshop_img, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/   
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name:     "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end

create_table "workshops", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "author"
  t.text     "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "category_id"
  t.string   "workshop_img_file_name"
  t.string   "workshop_img_content_type"
  t.integer  "workshop_img_file_size"
  t.datetime "workshop_img_updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: your config/routes.rb ?

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users
 resources :workshops
 root 'workshops#index'
 
    end

Answer (score 0):

Can we get some info on the error being produced? The rails error messages tend to be a bit more useful than in other languages. All I can see if you've said there is an error on line 2 of the form, if you can copy and paste the output of the error here then it should highlight the issue.

Comment: NoMethodError in Workshops#create
Showing C:/Users/mamaravilha/Documents/sampleteste/WorkshopTeste/app/views/workshops/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Comment: There we go! 1 sec

Comment: I just saw that when I create a workshop without a file upload it works! The problem might be with the peperclip/imagemagick configuration on windows, but I have followed all the steps...

Comment: So the problem is that @categories is nil, and as you've assigned it to Category.all, I"m assuming that means that you haven't added any categories to the database. It's trying to map out all of nil, which is throwing the error. After you've added some to your database then that should be fine (or at least you'll get past this error message!)

Comment: @Mark Category.all will provide an empty array if there are no categories in database, not `nil`

Comment: Did a Category.all in rails console:                                                                                   Category Load (18.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Category id: 1, name: "Montessori", created_at: "
2017-03-16 17:43:57", updated_at: "2017-03-16 17:43:57">, #<Category id: 2, name
: "Waldorf", created_at: "2017-03-16 17:44:47", updated_at: "2017-03-16 17:44:47
">, #<Category id: 3, name: "Educação Viva e Consciente", created_at: "2017-03-1
6 17:45:57", updated_at: "2017-03-16 17:45:57">]>
irb(main):003:0>

Comment: Look at my answer, I think I found the source of your problem. You should just add @categories variable (with appropriate value) to create action.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! In your `create` action you render 'new' view (if save fails) which requires a `@categories`. But you don't create them in create action. There is `nil` comes from.